# Probability of extracting 1 Red ball from a urn and then k Red balls at the sequent extraction

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm struggling with a quite basic probability problem, and my knowledge in this field is not very deep, so I would appreciate some help. Here is the problem.

**Problem formulation**
We have some balls in a urn:

- B = total numbers of balls
- R = quantity of RED balls
- G = B – R = quantity of GREEN balls
- N = number of extractions
- K’ = B/N
- k = a parameter we need for the questions. 
  $k \in [1, K’]$

At each extraction n we need to extract K’ balls from the box (BULK estraction).
No replacement.
 The game finish when we have no more balls in the box.

**Questions**

 Probability that:

1. At least $k$ RED balls are extracted in a generic extraction $n$
2. At least $1$ RED ball is extracted in generic extraction $n$ AND then at least $k$ RED balls are extracted in extraction $n+1$

**Possible solution**

Given that:

- $ \binom{B}{K'} $ = number of different possible ways to extract K’ balls from a box of B balls
- $ \binom{R}{k} $ = number of different possible ways to extract k red balls given that there are R red balls
- $ \binom{G}{K'-k} $ = number of different possible ways to extract K’-k green balls given that there are G green balls

1. I think to have correctly solved this point, since I've also found an analogous post. The probability of getting at least k RED balls in a generic extraction should be always equal to
   $$P = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{K'-k}\binom{R}{k+i}\binom{G}{K'-k-i}}{\binom{B}{K'}}$$
   Since I am considering the problem before any extraction has happen, my guess should be uniformely distributed among the N extractions.
2. For the second point I am kinda lost. I have think to define:

- A = At least $k$ RED balls are extracted in extraction $n+1$
- B = At least $1$ RED ball is extracted in generic extraction $n$
  So $$ P(A\land B) = {P(A | B)}{P(B)}$$
  $P(B)$ should be in theory similar to the result of point 1. But I wasn't able to model $P(A | B)$. I have tried various formulation but they all give me quite strange result.

Thank in advance to anyone who will help!

Comment: If you need exact results, I'd compute the joint distribution case by case.  That is, compute $P(i,j)$ where $i$ is the number of red balls extracted in the given selection and $j$ is the number selected in the next.  Sum over the good cases.  In some instances it might be computationally easier to go backwards (e.g. if $k$ is near $1$ or if $k$ is near $K'$).  Simplifying assumptions could help a lot...if, say, you knew that there were lots and lots of red balls relative to the selection size, you could treat the two selections as if they were independent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just for you to notice, I made a mistake in naming the 2 events A, B. They were inverted. Sorry for that, now I just edit the question.